# cs106b library vector.cpp error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'

Tags: c++, vector

relating to `Vector<ElemType>::Vector(int capacity)`

- C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '<'
- C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int
- C2988: unrecognizable template declaration/definition
- C2059: syntax error : '<'

relating to `Vector<ElemType>::~Vector()`

- C2588: '::~Vector' : illegal global destructor

```
/*
 * File: private/vector.cpp
 * Last modified on Fri Jun  5 16:19:42 2009 by eroberts
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * This file contains the implementation of the vector.h interface.
 * Because of the way C++ compiles templates, this code must be
 * available to the compiler when it reads the header file.
 */

#ifdef _vector_h

#include "stdafx.h"

/*
 * Vector class implementation
 * ---------------------------
 * The Vector is internally managed as a dynamic array of elements.
 * It tracks capacity (numAllocated) separately from size (numUsed).
 * All access is bounds-checked for safety.
 */

template <typename ElemType>
Vector<ElemType>::Vector(int capacity) {
    elements = new ElemType[capacity];
    numAllocated = capacity;
    numUsed = 0;
    timestamp = 0L;
}

template <typename ElemType>
Vector<ElemType>::~Vector() {
    if (elements != NULL) delete[] elements;
}

template <typename ElemType>
inline int Vector<ElemType>::size() {
    return numUsed;
}

template <typename ElemType>
bool Vector<ElemType>::isEmpty() {
    return size() == 0;
}

template <typename ElemType>
ElemType Vector<ElemType>::getAt(int index) {
    checkRange(index, "getAt");
    return elements[index];
}

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::setAt(int index, ElemType elem) {
    checkRange(index, "setAt");
    elements[index] = elem;
}

/* Private method: checkRange
 * --------------------------
 * Verifies that index is in range for this vector, if not, raises an
 * error.  The verb string is used in the error message to describe the
 * operation that caused the range error, .e.g "setAt" or "removeAt".
 */

template <typename ElemType>
inline void Vector<ElemType>::checkRange(int index, const char *verb) {
    if (index < 0 || index >= size()) {
        Error("Attempt to " + string(verb) + " index "
              + IntegerToString(index) + " in a vector of size "
              + IntegerToString(size()) + ".");
    }
}

template <typename ElemType>
inline ElemType &Vector<ElemType>::operator[](int index) {
    checkRange(index, "access");
    return elements[index];
}

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::add(ElemType elem) {
    insertAt(numUsed, elem);
}

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::insertAt(int index, ElemType elem) {
    if (numAllocated == numUsed) enlargeCapacity();
    if (index != numUsed) checkRange(index, "insertAt");
    for (int i = numUsed; i > index; i--) {
        elements[i] = elements[i-1];
    }
    elements[index] = elem;
    numUsed++;
    timestamp++;
}

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::removeAt(int index) {
    checkRange(index, "removeAt");
    for (int i = index; i < numUsed-1; i++) {
        elements[i] = elements[i+1];
    }
    numUsed--;
    timestamp++;
}

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::clear() {
    delete[] elements;
    elements = NULL;
    numUsed = numAllocated = 0;
    timestamp++;
}

template <typename ElemType>
const Vector<ElemType> &Vector<ElemType>::operator=(const Vector & rhs) {
    if (this != &rhs) {
        clear();
        copyInternalData(rhs);
        timestamp = 0L;
    }
    return *this;
}

template <typename ElemType>
Vector<ElemType>::Vector(const Vector & rhs) {
    copyInternalData(rhs);
    timestamp = 0L;
}

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::mapAll(void (*fn)(ElemType)) {
    long t0 = timestamp;
    for (int i = 0; i < numUsed; i++) {
        if (timestamp != t0) {
            Error("Vector structure has been modified");
        }
        fn(elements[i]);
    }
}

template <typename ElemType>
template <typename ClientDataType>
void Vector<ElemType>::mapAll(void (*fn)(ElemType, ClientDataType&),
                              ClientDataType & data) {
    long t0 = timestamp;
    for (int i = 0; i < numUsed; i++) {
        if (timestamp != t0) {
            Error("Vector structure has been modified");
        }
        fn(elements[i], data);
    }
}

/*
 * Vector::Iterator class implementation
 * ----------------------------------
 * The Iterator for Vector maintains a pointer to the original Vector and
 * an index into that vector that identifies the next element to return.
 */

template <typename ElemType>
Vector<ElemType>::Iterator::Iterator() {
    vp = NULL;
}

template <typename ElemType>
typename Vector<ElemType>::Iterator Vector<ElemType>::iterator() {
    return Iterator(this);
}

template <typename ElemType>
Vector<ElemType>::Iterator::Iterator(Vector *vecRef) {
    vp = vecRef;
    curIndex = 0;
    timestamp = vp->timestamp;
}

template <typename ElemType>
bool Vector<ElemType>::Iterator::hasNext() {
    if (vp == NULL) Error("hasNext called on uninitialized iterator");
    if (timestamp != vp->timestamp) {
        Error("Vector structure has been modified");
    }
    return curIndex < vp->size();
}

template <typename ElemType>
ElemType Vector<ElemType>::Iterator::next() {
    if (vp == NULL) Error("next called on uninitialized iterator");
    if (!hasNext()) {
        Error("Attempt to get next from iterator"
              " where hasNext() is false");
    }
    return (*vp)[curIndex++];
}

template <typename ElemType>
ElemType Vector<ElemType>::foreachHook(FE_State & fe) {
    if (fe.state == 0) fe.iter = new Iterator(this);
    if (((Iterator *) fe.iter)->hasNext()) {
        fe.state = 1;
        return ((Iterator *) fe.iter)->next();
    } else {
        fe.state = 2;
        return ElemType();
    }
}

/* Private method: enlargeCapacity
 * -------------------------------
 * Doubles the current capacity of the vector's internal storage,
 * copying all existing values.
 */

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::enlargeCapacity() {
    numAllocated = (numAllocated == 0 ? 10 : numAllocated*2);
    ElemType *newArray = new ElemType[numAllocated];
    for (int i = 0; i < numUsed; i++) {
        newArray[i] = elements[i];
    }
    delete[] elements;
    elements = newArray;
}

/* Private method: copyInternalData
 * --------------------------------
 * Common code factored out of the copy constructor and operator= to
 * copy the contents from the other vector.
 */

template <typename ElemType>
void Vector<ElemType>::copyInternalData(const Vector & other) {
    elements = new ElemType[other.numUsed];
    for (int i = 0; i < other.numUsed; i++) {
        elements[i] = other.elements[i];
    }
    numUsed = other.numUsed;
    numAllocated = other.numUsed;
}

#endif
```

example of vector class defind

```
/*
 * File: set.h
 * Last modified on Thu Jun 11 09:17:43 2009 by eroberts
 *      modified on Tue Jan  2 14:34:06 2007 by zelenski
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * This interface file contains the Set class template, a
 * collection for efficiently storing a set of distinct elements.
 */

#ifndef _set_h
#define _set_h

#include "cmpfn.h"
#include "bst.h"
#include "vector.h"
#include "foreach.h"

/*
 * Class: Set
 * ----------
 * This interface defines a class template that stores a collection of
 * distinct elements, using a sorted relation on the elements to
 * provide efficient managaement of the collection.
 * For maximum generality, the Set is supplied as a class template.
 * The element type is determined by the client. The client configures
 * the set to hold values of a specific type, e.g. Set<int> or
 * Set<studentT>. The one requirement on the element type is that the
 * client must supply a comparison function that compares two elements
 * (or be willing to use the default comparison function that uses
 * the built-on operators  < and ==).
 */

template <typename ElemType>
class Set {

public:

/* Forward references */
    class Iterator;

/*
 * Constructor: Set
 * Usage: Set<int> set;
 *        Set<student> students(CompareStudentsById);
 *        Set<string> *sp = new Set<string>;
 * -----------------------------------------
 * The constructor initializes an empty set. The optional
 * argument is a function pointer that is applied to
 * two elements to determine their relative ordering. The
 * comparison function should return 0 if the two elements
 * are equal, a negative result if first is "less than" second,
 * and a positive resut if first is "greater than" second. If
 * no argument is supplied, the OperatorCmp template is used as
 * a default, which applies the bulit-in < and == to the
 * elements to determine ordering.
 */
    Set(int (*cmpFn)(ElemType, ElemType) = OperatorCmp);

/*
 * Destructor: ~Set
 * Usage: delete sp;
 * -----------------
 * The destructor deallocates  storage associated with set.
 */
    ~Set();

/*
 * Method: size
 * Usage: count = set.size();
 * --------------------------
 * This method returns the number of elements in this set.
 */
    int size();

/*
 * Method: isEmpty
 * Usage: if (set.isEmpty())...
 * ----------------------------
 * This method returns true if this set contains no
 * elements, false otherwise.
 */
    bool isEmpty();

/*
 * Method: add
 * Usage: set.add(value);
 * ----------------------
 * This method adds an element to this set. If the
 * value was already contained in the set, the existing entry is
 * overwritten by the new copy, and the set's size is unchanged.
 * Otherwise, the value is added and set's size increases by one.
 */
    void add(ElemType elem);

/*
 * Method: remove
 * Usage: set.remove(value);
 * -----------------------
 * This method removes an element from this set. If the
 * element was not contained in the set, the set is unchanged.
 * Otherwise, the element is removed and the set's size decreases
 * by one.
 */
    void remove(ElemType elem);

/*
 * Method: contains
 * Usage: if (set.contains(value))...
 * -----------------------------------
 * Returns true if the element in this set, false otherwise.
 */
    bool contains(ElemType elem);

/*
 * Method: find
 * Usage: eptr = set.find(elem);
 * -----------------------------
 * If the element is contained in this set, returns a pointer
 * to that elem.  The pointer allows you to update that element
 * in place. If element is not contained in this set, NULL is
 * returned.
 */
    ElemType *find(ElemType elem);

/*
 * Method: equals
 * Usage: if (set.equals(set2)) . . .
 * -----------------------------------
 * This predicate function implements the equality relation
 * on sets.  It returns true if this set and set2 contain
 * exactly the same elements, false otherwise.
 */
    bool equals(Set & otherSet);

/*
 * Method: isSubsetOf
 * Usage: if (set.isSubsetOf(set2)) . . .
 * --------------------------------------
 * This predicate function implements the subset relation
 * on sets.  It returns true if all of the elements in this
 * set are contained in set2.  The set2 does not have to
 * be a proper subset (that is, it may be equals).
 */
    bool isSubsetOf(Set & otherSet);

/*
 * Methods: unionWith, intersectWith, subtract
 * Usage: set.unionWith(set2);
 *        set.intersectWith(set2);
 *        set.subtract(set2);
 * -------------------------------
 * These fmember unctions modify the receiver set as follows:
 *
 * set.unionWith(set2);      Adds all elements from set2 to this set.
 * set.intersectWith(set2);  Removes any element not in set2 from this set.
 * set.subtract(set2);       Removes all element in set2 from this set.
 */
    void unionWith(Set & otherSet);
    void intersectWith(Set & otherSet);
    void subtract(Set & otherSet);

/*
 * Method: clear
 * Usage: set.clear();
 * -------------------
 * This method removes all elements from this set. The
 * set is made empty and will have size() = 0 after being cleared.
 */
    void clear();

/*
 * SPECIAL NOTE: mapping/iteration support
 * ---------------------------------------
 * The set supports both a mapping operation and an iterator which
 * allow the client access to all elements one by one.  In general,
 * these  are intended for _viewing_ elements and can behave
 * unpredictably if you attempt to modify the set's contents during
 * mapping/iteration.
 */

/*
 * Method: mapAll
 * Usage: set.mapAll(Print);
 * -------------------------
 * This method iterates through this set's contents
 * and calls the function fn once for each element.
 */
    void mapAll(void (*fn)(ElemType elem));

/*
 * Method: mapAll
 * Usage: set.mapAll(PrintToFile, outputStream);
 * --------------------------------------------
 * This method iterates through this set's contents
 * and calls the function fn once for each element, passing
 * the element and the client's data. That data can be of whatever
 * type is needed for the client's callback.
 */
    template <typename ClientDataType>
    void mapAll(void (*fn)(ElemType elem, ClientDataType & data),
                ClientDataType & data);

/*
 * Method: iterator
 * Usage: iter = set.iterator();
 * -----------------------------
 * This method creates an iterator that allows the client to
 * iterate through the elements in this set.  The elements are
 * returned in the order determined by the comparison function.
 *
 * The idiomatic code for accessing elements using an iterator is
 * to create the iterator from the collection and then enter a loop
 * that calls next() while hasNext() is true, like this:
 *
 *     Set<int>::Iterator iter = set.iterator();
 *     while (iter.hasNext()) {
 *         int value = iter.next();
 *         . . .
 *     }
 *
 * This pattern can be abbreviated to the following more readable form:
 *
 *     foreach (int value in set) {
 *         . . .
 *     }
 *
 * To avoid exposing the details of the class, the definition of the
 * Iterator class itself appears in the private/set.h file.
 */
    Iterator iterator();

private:

#include "private/set.h"

};

#include "private/set.cpp"

#endif
```

This [class Vector](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/documentation/vector_8h.html) is a standard component of a library, so it should compile - intuition is that either a header is missing or the compiler settings are wrong. I obtained this copy from the [sourceforge CS106B library](http://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib/files/)

Also, here are the vector.h public and private files

```
/*
 * File: private/vector.h
 * Last modified on Fri Jun  5 15:39:26 2009 by eroberts
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * This file contains the private section of the vector.h interface.
 * This portion of the class definition is taken out of the vector.h
 * header so that the client need not have to see all of these
 * details.
 */

public:

/*
 * Class: Vector<ElemType>::Iterator
 * ---------------------------------
 * This interface defines a nested class within the Vector template that
 * provides iterator access to the Vector contents.
 */
    class Iterator : public FE_Iterator {
    public:
        Iterator();
        bool hasNext();
        ElemType next();

    private:
        Iterator(Vector *vecRef);
        Vector *vp;
        int curIndex;
        long timestamp;
        friend class Vector;
    };
    friend class Iterator;
    ElemType foreachHook(FE_State & _fe);

/*
 * Deep copying support
 * --------------------
 * This copy constructor and operator= are defined to make a
 * deep copy, making it possible to pass/return vectors by value
 * and assign from one vector to another. The entire contents of
 * the vector, including all elements, are copied. Each vector
 * element is copied from the original vector to the copy using
 * assignment (operator=). Making copies is generally avoided
 * because of the expense and thus, vectors are typically passed
 * by reference, however, when a copy is needed, these operations
 * are supported.
 */
    const Vector & operator=(const Vector & rhs);
    Vector(const Vector & rhs);

private:
    ElemType *elements;
    int numAllocated, numUsed;
    long timestamp;

    void checkRange(int index, const char *msg);
    void enlargeCapacity();
    void copyInternalData(const Vector & other);
```

and

```
/*
 * File: vector.h
 * Last modified on Fri Jun  5 15:35:35 2009 by eroberts
 *      modified on Tue Jan  2 13:56:15 2007 by zelenski
 * -----------------------------------------------------
 * This interface file contains the Vector class template, an
 * efficient, safer, convenient replacement for the built-in array.
 */

#ifndef _vector_h
#define _vector_h

#include "genlib.h"
#include "strutils.h"
#include "foreach.h"

/*
 * Class: Vector
 * -------------
 * This interface defines a class template that stores a homogeneous
 * indexed collection. The basic operations are similar to those
 * in the built-in array type, with the added features of dynamic
 * memory management, bounds-checking on indexes, and convenient
 * insert/remove operations. Like an array, but better!
 * For maximum generality, the Vector is supplied as a class template.
 * The client specializes the vector to hold values of a specific
 * type, e.g. Vector<int> or Vector<studentT>, as needed
 */

template <typename ElemType>
class Vector {

public:

/* Forward references */
    class Iterator;

/*
 * Constructor: Vector
 * Usage: Vector<int> vec;
 *        Vector<student> dormlist(200);
 *        Vector<string> *vp = new Vector<string>;
 * -----------------------------------------------
 * The constructor initializes a new empty vector. The optional
 * argument is a hint about the expected number of elements that
 * this vector will hold, which allows vector to configure itself
 * for that capacity during initialization.  If not specified,
 * it is initialized with default capacity and grows as elements
 * are added. Note that capacity does NOT mean size, a newly
 * constructed vector always has size() = 0. A large starting
 * capacity allows you to add that many elements without requiring
 * any internal reallocation. The explicit keyword is required to
 * avoid accidental construction of a vector from an int.
 */
    explicit Vector(int sizeHint = 0);

/*
 * Destructor: ~Vector
 * Usage: delete vp;
 * -----------------
 * The destructor deallocates storage associated with this vector.
 */
    ~Vector();

/*
 * Method: size
 * Usage: nElems = vec.size();
 * ---------------------------
 * This method returns the number of elements in
 * this vector.
 */
    int size();

/*
 * Method: isEmpty
 * Usage: if (vec.isEmpty())...
 * -----------------------------
 * This method returns true if this vector contains no
 * elements, false otherwise.
 */
    bool isEmpty();

/*
 * Method: getAt
 * Usage: val = vec.getAt(3);
 * --------------------------
 * This method returns the element at the specified index
 * in this vector. Elements are indexed starting from 0.  A call to
 * vec.getAt(0) returns the first element, vec.getAt(vec.size()-1)
 * returns the last. Raises an error if index is outside the range
 * [0, size()-1].
 */
    ElemType getAt(int index);

/*
 * Method: setAt
 * Usage: vec.setAt(3, value);
 * ---------------------------
 * This method replaces the element at the specified index
 * in this vector with a new value.  The previous value at that
 * index is overwritten with the new value. The size of the vector
 * is unchanged. Raises an error if index is not within the
 * range [0, size()-1].
 */
    void setAt(int index, ElemType value);

/*
 * Method: operator[]
 * Usage: vec[0] = vec[1];
 * -----------------------
 * This method overloads [] to access elements from
 * this vector. This allows the client to use array-like notation
 * to get/set individual vector elements. Returns a reference to
 * the element to allow in-place modification of values. Raises
 * an error if index is not within the range [0, size()-1].
 */
    ElemType & operator[](int index);

/*
 * Method: add
 * Usage: vec.add(value);
 * ----------------------
 * This method adds an element to the end of this vector.
 * The vector's size increases by one.
 */
    void add(ElemType elem);

/*
 * Method: insertAt
 * Usage: vec.insertAt(0, value);
 * ------------------------------
 * This method inserts the element into this vector at
 * the specified index, shifting all subsequent elements one
 * index higher. A call to vec.insertAt(0, val) inserts a new
 * element at the beginning, vec.insertAt(vec.size(), val) add
 * a new element to the end. The vector's size increases by one.
 * Raises an error if index is outside the range [0, size()].
 */
    void insertAt(int index, ElemType elem);

/*
 * Method: removeAt
 * Usage: vec.removeAt(3);
 * -----------------------
 * This method removes the element at the specified
 * index from this vector, shifting all subsequent elements one
 * index lower. A call to vec.removeAt(0) removes the first
 * element, vec.removeAt(vec.size()-1), removes the last. The
 * vector's size decreases by one. Raises an error if index is
 * outside the range [0, size()-1].
 */
    void removeAt(int index);

/*
 * Method: clear
 * Usage: vec.clear();
 * -------------------
 * This method removes all elements from this vector. The
 * vector is made empty and will have size() = 0.
 */
    void clear();

/*
 * SPECIAL NOTE: mapping/iteration support
 * ---------------------------------------
 * The Vector class supports both a mapping operation and an iterator which
 * allow the client access to all elements one by one.  In general,
 * these  are intended for _viewing_ elements and can behave
 * unpredictably if you attempt to modify the vector's contents during
 * mapping/iteration.
 */

/*
 * Method: mapAll
 * Usage: vector.mapAll(Print);
 * ----------------------------
 * This method iterates through this vector's contents
 * and calls the function fn once for each element.
 */
    void mapAll(void (*fn)(ElemType elem));

/*
 * Method: mapAll
 * Usage: vector.mapAll(PrintToFile, outputStream);
 * ------------------------------------------------
 * This method iterates through this vector's contents
 * and calls the function fn once for each element, passing
 * the element and the client's data. That data can be of whatever
 * type is needed for the client's callback.
 */
    template <typename ClientDataType>
    void mapAll(void (*fn)(ElemType elem, ClientDataType & data),
                ClientDataType & data);

/*
 * Method: iterator
 * Usage: iter = vector.iterator();
 * --------------------------------
 * This method creates an iterator that allows the client to
 * iterate through the elements in this vector.  The elements are
 * returned in index order.
 *
 * The idiomatic code for accessing elements using an iterator is
 * to create the iterator from the collection and then enter a loop
 * that calls next() while hasNext() is true, like this:
 *
 *     Vector<int>::Iterator iter = vector.iterator();
 *     while (iter.hasNext()) {
 *         int elem = iter.next();
 *         . . .
 *     }
 *
 * This pattern can be abbreviated to the following more readable form:
 *
 *     foreach (int elem in vector) {
 *         . . .
 *     }
 *
 * To avoid exposing the details of the class, the definition of the
 * Iterator class itself appears in the private/vector.h file.
 */
    Iterator iterator();

private:

#include "private/vector.h"

};

#include "private/vector.cpp"

#endif
```

Comment: Where is the class `Vector` defined? In some header included by _stdafx.h_?

Comment: it is defined in the classes that use it; I edited the post to include an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite its name, you must not compile vector.cpp from that project. The .CPP file exists only to be `#include`d from vector.h.

Somehow you are compiling vector.cpp directly. The error messages stem from the missing definition of `template<> class Vector { ... }`.

Comment: vector.cpp is included as a source file, should it be excluded but remain in the same folder as the project? And, why is this, so I can not make this mistake again.

Comment: The people who created that library used an atypical naming convention. In their scheme, vector.cpp should live in "include/private/vector.cpp" (which I suppose is not "the same folder as the project"). None of the CPP files in that directory should be compiled. (Depending upon your choice of IDE or build system, you may need to 'exclude' those files.)

Comment: the compiler is VS2008; whyare the private files excluded from the compiler?

Comment: I excluded all the private files, including the private headers. do you have a short explanation for the 'why' these are excluded?

Comment: Short explanation: because they are (poorly named) headers.